# Show popup with confirmation button using addMessage and commandlink

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, dynamic-visualforce

I have a requirement where I have to create a popup (using addMessage) that display two options: confirm and cancel, each of these options has an action.

I already tried passing a command link in the variable of the addMessage like this:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, '<apex:commandLink value="Confirm" action="{! addContact }" rendered="true" />'));
```

but it didn't work.

Someone could help me with this?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: I've rolled this post back to the version that was answered. Please do not deface it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't render a component this way. You could use [Dynamic Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_intro.htm), but this is probably overkill. I'd just use normal markup (you can add a message dynamically):

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!showDialog}">
  {!message}
  <apex:commandButton label="Cancel" onclick="{!closeDialog}" />
  <apex:commandLink label="Confirm" onclick="{!confirmDialog}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Which you'd then control via Apex:

```
showDialog = true;
message = 'Are you sure you want to create a new contact?';
```

You could even build this as a [Visualforce Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm) for reusability on multiple pages or for multiple uses.

Comment: That's really not possible, I searched about every way to do that but without success, I will use normal markup, thanks for your help!